# How to get full metadata inertia metrix, inertia center, mass, volumn, ect.. from GET Properties

Tags: autodesk-forge

When we use this API from model derivative to retreive metadata.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/

We could not get all info same as example doc.
"Mass Properties": {
"Area": "7000 millimeter^2",
"Volume": "25000 millimeter^3"
}
"properties": {
"Center of Gravity:": "-13.452 mm, -9.879 mm, -40.735 mm",
"Name": "Box"
}
are missing in response.

Does any one know how to get them, or full info?

Comment: What properties are extracted depends on the input file type. What file are you using as input?